# Laravel belongsToMany, can't resolve it

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many

I have a jokes, joke_tags, tags table. And I'm trying to get all tags that match the joke ID.

```
class Joke extends Model
{
    public function tags() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'joke_tags', 'tag_id', 'joke_id');
    }
}
```

My Tag model:

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    public function jokes() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Joke');
    }
}
```

Both functions `tags()` and `jokes()` don't work... I've been struggling with that for 2 hours now.

My db layout:

```
Schema::create('jokes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('ID');
    $table->string('author');
    $table->longText('joke');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('joke_tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('ID');
    $table->integer('joke_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('joke_id')->references('ID')->on('jokes');
    $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('ID')->on('tags');
});

Schema::create('joke_votes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('ID');
    $table->integer('joke_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('joke_id')->references('ID')->on('jokes');
    $table->string('IP');
    $table->boolean('type');
});

Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('ID');
    $table->string('tag');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to both of your models and you would be good to go.

```
protected $primaryKey = 'ID';
```

EDIT: You should define the relationships as follows besides adding the above property.

```
class Joke extends Model
{
    public function tags() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'joke_tags', 'joke_id', 'tag_id');
    }
}

class Tag extends Model
{
    public function jokes() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Joke', 'joke_tags', 'tag_id', 'joke_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Because laravel assumes your Primary keys are named as 'id'. You change it and then you need to tell it what you have changed to.

Comment: @tempestor did this answer helped you? I can see you also use wrong syntax in relations, so they do not work. Did you fix this?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin thanks for pointing it out. Yes of course he should add primarykey property,  but there were some other issues that I added in my answer

Comment: @tempestor voting up an answer is very different from accepting an answer.